# getting error when trying to add liquidity

Tags: error, liquidity-provider, transferfrom, failed-transaction, liquidity

So I tried to add liquidity in Rocketswap for the Basechain, in the contract I used the router adress of Rocketswap. But I get this error, I have a feeling it has to do with the Transfer_from function... but I am not sure
If somebody can help me I start to turn grey

https://basescan.org/tx/0xb1b9ce687fa7f191b7efa0d7ef7619c7723016f8f95af3bc515d439114d87804